# Override SASS class

Tags: css, css-specificity

I want to define a style for components I use to filter a list. I made a class to select all of them, and then I want to override some of the selected classes.
Some code being worth a thousand words :

```
div[class*="filter-"] {
      (some property)
}

.filter-specific {
   (do something more specific)
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't work. I though that the order of definition was important but it doesn't appear to be the case. And I can't put `!important` everywhere. So what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because CSS specificity.

`div[class*="filter-"]` has better specificity (`div` + `[class*="filter-"]`) then `.filter-specific`.

You can test it with this [CSS Specificity calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/).

If `.filter-specific` will always be a `div`, then you can use it like:

```css
div[class*="filter-"] {
  color: red;
}

div.filter-specific {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-foo">bar</div>
<div class="filter-specific">spec</div>
```

Reference: [MDN CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: You could remove `div` from both selectors, too, yes?

Comment: @NathanArthur sure, class has better specificity so the result will be the same.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you ! I didn't know css had such mechanism to order priority.